# How to play as Orochi in The King Of Fighters '97?

Tags: the-king-of-fighters-97

I know the codes of Orochi Leona, Iori, Chris, Yashiro & Shermie:

☞ **Orochi Leona:** Highlight Leona.

> Hold down the Start button and press Up, Down, Up, Down, Up, Down, B + D.

☞ **Orochi Iori:** Highlight Iori.

> Hold down the Start button and press Left, Right, Left, Right, Left, Right, A + C.

☞ **Orochi Team:** Enable either the Orochi Iori or Orochi Leona codes.

> Highlight Leona, then hold Start and press Up, Left, Down, Right, Up, Down, B + C.

But how do I enable Orochi? Please help.

***EDIT:*** Some said Orochi is left to Iori, but when I move left from Iori pointer goes to Billy as shown in picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I found a few hacked roms with all the chars (including orochi) unlocked when you first press start, but the power gauges are maxed out at all times, which doesn't seem fair.  Then I found a page with a bunch of *.dat files that you can put in the kawaks cheats folder.  I was lucky to have found it within a few hours, instead of a few days.  But here it is:

http://web.tiscali.it/bisigo/emulation/emulation.html

So now you can play 3 Orochis in one team! LOL

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://www.gamewinners.com/NG/KingOfFighters97.htm):

> **Fight as Orochi:**
>   Enable the *Fight as Orochi Iori*, *Fight as Orochi Leona*, and the *Enable Orochi Band Team* codes. Then, highlight regular Iori and press **Left**. The pointer will go to a blank location. However, the picture on the bottom left screen it will show Orochi. Then, press any button.

**EDIT:** I checked a few more sites, [GameSpot](http://www.gamespot.com/the-king-of-fighters-97/cheats/) and IGN state Orochi as a playable character in the PS1 and Saturn versions, and only in Practice mode and Versus mode on the PS1 version.

Comments to [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EwULtYdd_c) states he used the Kawaks cheat.dat to play as Orochi on the arcade version, but he doesn't specify how.

Comment: I haven't played this game in a while, but I thought Orochi was in the empty space between Orochi Iori and Orochi Leona on the Character Select menu. See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=g-vWCwen0hY#t=49s

Comment: I haven't played this game since my MAME days 10 years ago. I only copied this info from the website linked. Feel free to correct my answer

Comment: @Krazer I did as you said but there is no Orochi, please check my edit.

Comment: Updated my answer, I believe this only works on the PlayStation/Saturn console version